# Make background inherit from selectableItemBackground

Tags: android, layout

Right now my view (framelayout) has

```
         android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

I want to add a bottom border to it (when it's activated). One option is to add 1 more layer inside with

```
         android:background="@drawable/my_bgr"
```

but that's kinda lame - grows view hierarchy for no reason.

Another option is to put my drawable as a bgr of the view but change it to handle ripple effect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
            <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
                <color android:color="@android:color/white" />
            </item>
        </ripple>
    </item>
    <item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
        <selector>
            <item android:state_activated="true">
                <shape>
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                    <stroke
                            android:width="2dp"
                            android:color="#FF0000" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </selector>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

That's kinda cool, but I wasnt to support minSdk=15 (how do I do that?) and if one day I change the theme of the app, this will keep the ripple effect. Is there any way to "inherit" from selectableItemBackground and add a border?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it can be done for 21+ android, where https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26251 is fixed.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" />
<item android:top="-2dp" android:right="-2dp" android:left="-2dp">
    <selector>
        <item android:state_activated="true">
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <stroke
                        android:width="2dp"
                        android:color="#910E12" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Before that I think I'm stuck with adding 1 more layer to my view hierarchy (first layer has ?android:attr/selectableItemBackground and the second my custom border background)

Answer (score 1):

Just make `<item android:drawable="?selectableItemBackground"/>` your last layer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FF0000" />
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="?selectableItemBackground"/>

</layer-list>
```

please read this answer for know difference between `?selectableItemBackground` and `?android:attrs/selectableItemBackground`